# Anime about old people nursed in high-tech beds

Tags: roujin-z

At least 7 years ago I was shown an Anime that revolved around the premise that due to medical advances and low birth rate there were a lot of old people and as such there was a huge demand for old-person care nurses. One of the main characters was such a nurse, but there was also another guy as a main character.

Anyway, a company develops some high tech nursing beds that take care of bodily function needs and provides mobility but the prototype bed (and it's AI) begins interfacing with various electronics in the room and eventually becomes mobile and begins consuming other machines and devices and this bed (along with the old guy still inside) begins terrorizing downtown. Eventually the military is brought in and the bed is stopped somehow.

I'm surprised that I couldn't find it myself, but maybe I'm just unlucky. Any ideas? It's either a movie or a OVA I'd think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [Roujin Z](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roujin_Z):

> Roujin Z is set in early 21st century Japan. A group of scientists and hospital administrators, under the direction of the Ministry of Public Welfare, have developed the Z-001: a computerized hospital bed with robotic features. The Z-001 takes complete care of the patient: it can dispense food and medicine, remove excretory waste, bathe and exercise the patient lying within its frame. The bed is driven by its own built-in nuclear power reactor — and in the event of an atomic meltdown, the bed (including the patient lying within) would become automatically sealed in concrete. The first patient to be "volunteered" to test the bed is a dying widower named Kiyuro Takazawa. He is an invalid who is cared for by a young nursing student named Haruko. The electronic elements within the Z-001 somehow manage to transcribe Takazawa's thoughts through Haruko's office computer, and he uses the communication to cry for help.

[image: Hello, nurse.]

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZH4K3OkRqL8